# Create index pattern in Kibana circle for 'creating' is spinning forever

Tags: elasticsearch

Installed software:
  Elastic version:
  Kibana:

I hit the trouble described here: [high disk watermark [90%] exceeded](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/unable-to-create-index-pattern-from-kibana/167184)  One way to spot the sign pointing at this state is to open Developer Tools in FF and see the 403 Error returned from server along with checking Elastic server logs. Unfortunately in the aforementioned link there is no description how to resolve this error since disk cleanup on Elastic server does not help.

Comment: Well, the trouble is disk full... time for spring cleaning.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what needs to be done in order to bring your cluster back into a modifiable state:

1. Clean up some disk space on Elastic host.
2. Execute: `curl -XPUT "http://elastic_host:9200/_cluster/settings" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "persistent" : {"cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled" : false }}'`
3. Execute: `curl -XPUT "http://elastic_host:9200/_settings" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"index": { "blocks": { "read_only_allow_delete": false }}}'`